# Creation of Journal entries when Updated from SQL + AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, journaling

AS400: If I update a file using 1. STRSQL(from command line)  2. Update/Insert/Delete statement in a SQLRPGLE program, would it create a Journal entry?(File is properly journaled)

Answer (score 0):

yes, both. And even with a standard RPG write/update operation

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It would be kind of useless if omitted some types of database transactions.